# Link Namespace error=invalid_client_id&error_description=client%20identifier%20invalid

Tags: managed-package, trailhead, namespace

Following occurred while executing this [Build First Generation Managed Packages with Salesforce CLI - Setup your Dev Hub Playground Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/first_generation_managed_packages/set_up_your_dev_hub_playground)

`error=invalid_client_id&error_description=client%20identifier%20invalid`

which appears in popup authorization window upon clicking Link Namespace in Dev Hub org

Comment: I think that you should accept your own answer. It was useful for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a timing issue.  After setting up the

- Dev Hub playground
- Packaging Playground

and enabling the Dev Hub in the Dev Hub playground ...

you may need to wait a few minutes for the credentials to propagate in the SFDC backend. For me, it was the length of time to

- Google around to see if this error had been previously reported
- Log off/login and try again
- Attend to some personal needs

basically 10-15 mins and after the above, `Link Namespaces` presented a proper login window.

Note there is a [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EFcgQAG&title=click-link-namespace-in-dev-hub-opens-a-blank-page) related to opening a blank authorization window upon clicking Link Namespace (which was not my issue)

Comment: I've been having this issue every time I set up a new dev hub.
I recommend you waiting for not only a couple of minutes but an entire day!

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be related to the generated connected app not getting figured fully or correctly (and it appears *very* slow to deploy updates -- more than the standard 10 minute upperbound).

The [open issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EFcgQAG&title=click-link-namespace-in-dev-hub-opens-a-blank-page) has a work around that involves replacing the app, but you should be able to fix it if just waiting 10-15 minutes as the accepted answer suggests does not resolve this.

1. Go to Setup --> Manage Connected Apps.
2. Find the app that start with: `DEVHUB_`
3. Edit the App and make sure the callback URL's domain matches your My Domain setup.
4. Save the changes and wait -- really wait. It'll say 2-10 minutes but think 4-20.
5. Retry.